# Human readable date to DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, type-conversion

I need to convert from a "human readable" date format to DateTime, for example:

From: January 20, 2013
To: MM/dd/yyyy

Does anybody know what's the format or if there's one for doing this with DateTime.Parse and providing the format? I just want to check before jumping into a date parser.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: You can indeed do it with `DateTime.Parse`, by passing in an expected format. Does that not solve your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx)

`MMMM dd, yyyy` is a format string you're looking for.

Use [`DateTime.ParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w2sa9yss.aspx) or [`DateTime.TryParseExact`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044.aspx) to parse the datetime using specific format string.

After parsing you'll be able to print the value in format you want:

```
string input = "20, 2013";
DateTime value;

if (DateTime.TryParseExact(input, "dd, yyyy", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out value))
{
    string output = value.ToString("dd/MM/yyyy");
}
```

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thanks I was trying to build my expression but I was using MM dd yyyy so clearly I was missing the comma and two extra MM for specifying the month name rather than digits. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure your goal, but are you trying to format your `DateTime` based upon which `MM/dd/yyyy` format that you choose?

If you are you would simply do:

```
DateTime.Now.ToString(MM/dd/yyy);
DateTime.Now.ToString(MMMM, MM dd, yyyy);
DateTime.Now.ToString(MMMM, MM dd, yyyy hh:mm:ss);
```

Essentially you have to use these:

- Capital MM : Represents the Month, so MMMM (Also creates the Long Date).
- Lowercase d : Will represent the day.
- Lowercase y: Will represent the year.
- Then the hh:mm:ss will actually add an hour, minute, second.

You can also utilize `Parse` to also ensure it is correctly captured.

Essentially you can easily manage or alter the *Format* based on whatever you require.  MSDN has some great articles on this as well.

Hopefully that helps.  Looks like while I was posting a few answers got generated. So your going to get some solid feedback.